# Merge dataframe based on a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes based column column

```
import pandas as pd
# list of strings
lst1 = [1,1,2,2,3]
# list of int
lst2 = ["a","b","c"]

lst3 = [1]
# list of int
lst4 = ["f"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2)),
               columns =['id', 'str1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst3, lst4)),
               columns =['id', 'str2'])
```

To merge the dataframe I used merge, join, concat but its no giving desired result, expected result is as new df with three column id, str1, str2 with id column as "1","1" str1 column as "1","b" str2 columns as "f","f"

Expected output

```
id, str1, str2
1,   a,   f
a1,  b,   f
```

Comment: simply `df1.merge(df2, on='id')`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i tried this but it created multiple entry for duplicates value from df1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *merge* function here. The following code should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
# list of strings
lst1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
# list of int
lst2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
lst3 = [1]
# list of int
lst4 = ["f"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2)), columns=['id', 'str1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst3, lst4)), columns=['id', 'str2'])

# Merge the dataframes on the 'id' column
result_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='outer')
print(result_df)
```

The expected output should look this

```
  id str1 str2
0   1  a    f
1   1  b    f
```

Comment: I tried this, its not working

Comment: Make sure you have the compatible version of pandas library installed

Comment: of course, I have latest version

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='outer')
result_df.fillna('').groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ",".join(set(x)))
```

Output:

```
   id str1 str2
0   1  b,1    f
1   2    c
```

Another output:

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='outer')
result_df.fillna('').groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(",".join)
```

Output:

```
   id str1 str2
0   1  1,b  f,f
1   2    c
```

Comment: can you please look for the expected output, I need that

Comment: @Alexandra it isn't clear exactly what your output dataframe should be.  Can you create code that shows your expected output dataframe?

Comment: I have updated the expected output